# Unity Facebook Integration not using iOS Facebook Application for Login

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

According to iOS SDK documentation, Facebook Login on IOS should try Facebook Application (if installed) first and fall back to web view only if it is not installed. However, for our Unity application, it was opening web view straight away. While not critical, this certainly hurts user experience (by asking him to provide email/password which he might not readily remember) so we investigated it and fixed two bugs in Unity SDK.

I'm sharing it here to help any fellow devs having same problems, and also since this is the only feedback channel for Facebook Unity SDK team (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Although I appreciate the effort to share answers. Please use the correct format. Use separate questions if you have them. Place answers as an actual answer and accept them when you can so that people can see the question is answered. Do not embed questions in answers or answers in questions, it makes it just a tad harder to use the site.

Answer (score 0):

Here is first issue:

Symptom: Facebook Login in Unity application on iOS device not using installed Facebook Application for login, regardless of whether "URL Scheme Suffix" is set or not in "Facebook Settings" asset.

Cause: FacebookProstprocessor is unusually shy in updating Info.plist, and will not add "CFBundleURLTypes" entry if it already exists (in our case Fiksu post-processor was putting own stuff before FB).

Fix (use own paths):

```
diff --git a/prototype/Assets/Facebook/Editor/iOS/PlistMod.cs b/prototype/Assets/Facebook/Editor/iOS/PlistMod.cs
index 7cd6d38..b5e4876 100644
--- a/prototype/Assets/Facebook/Editor/iOS/PlistMod.cs
+++ b/prototype/Assets/Facebook/Editor/iOS/PlistMod.cs
@@ -89,8 +89,6 @@ namespace UnityEditor.FacebookEditor


             */
-            if(!HasKey(dict, "CFBundleURLTypes"))
-            {
             AddChildElement(doc, dict, "key", "CFBundleURLTypes");
             var urlSchemeTop = AddChildElement(doc, dict, "array");
             {
@@ -115,7 +113,6 @@ namespace UnityEditor.FacebookEditor
                     }
                 }
             }
-            }


             doc.Save(fullPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Second issue

Symptom: Facebook Login in Unity application on iOS device not using installed Facebook Application for login if "URL Scheme Suffix" is set.

Cause: FacebookProstprocessor doesn't write suffix into "CFBundleURLTypes" entry.

Fix (use own paths):

```
diff --git a/prototype/Assets/Facebook/Editor/FacebookPostprocess.cs b/prototype/Assets/Facebook/Editor/FacebookPostprocess.cs
index b69233f..b299905 100644
--- a/prototype/Assets/Facebook/Editor/FacebookPostprocess.cs
+++ b/prototype/Assets/Facebook/Editor/FacebookPostprocess.cs
@@ -34,7 +34,7 @@ namespace UnityEditor.FacebookEditor
                 }
                 project.Save();

-                PlistMod.UpdatePlist(path, FBSettings.AppId, FBSettings.AllAppIds);
+                PlistMod.UpdatePlist(path, FBSettings.AppId, FBSettings.AllAppIds, FBSettings.IosURLSuffix);
                 FixupFiles.FixSimulator(path);
                 FixupFiles.AddVersionDefine(path);
                 FixupFiles.FixColdStart(path);
diff --git a/prototype/Assets/Facebook/Editor/iOS/PlistMod.cs b/prototype/Assets/Facebook/Editor/iOS/PlistMod.cs
index f5ca29a..7cd6d38 100644
--- a/prototype/Assets/Facebook/Editor/iOS/PlistMod.cs
+++ b/prototype/Assets/Facebook/Editor/iOS/PlistMod.cs
@@ -44,7 +44,7 @@ namespace UnityEditor.FacebookEditor
             return false;
         }

-        public static void UpdatePlist(string path, string appId, string[] allPossibleAppIds)
+        public static void UpdatePlist(string path, string appId, string[] allPossibleAppIds, string iosUrlSuffix)
         {
             const string fileName = "Info.plist";
             string fullPath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
@@ -101,7 +101,16 @@ namespace UnityEditor.FacebookEditor
                         {
                             foreach(string currAppId in allPossibleAppIds)
                             {
-                                AddChildElement(doc, innerArray, "string", "fb" + currAppId);
+                                string schema;
+                                if (currAppId == appId && iosUrlSuffix != "")
+                                {
+                                    schema = "fb" + currAppId + iosUrlSuffix;
+                                }
+                                else
+                                {
+                                    schema = "fb" + currAppId;
+                                }
+                                AddChildElement(doc, innerArray, "string", schema);
                             }
                         }
                     }
```